# Ubuntu: Sharing internet connection via ad-hoc

Tags: ubuntu, internet, network-shares, ad-hoc-network

I have a laptop with Ubuntu and connected to internet through cable. I want to set up an ad-hoc network to share the internet connection via wi-fi. The other computer runs on Windows Vista.

I managed to do this in Windows 7, but I can't do it in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing) Ubuntu wiki page explains everything.

Comment: It actually does not explain how to share the internet connection through the wireless card. However I already solved the problem, but only with WEP security.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it is obvious that after connection is estabilished, WiFi card is behaving like the Ethernet one.